# Dynamic Distribution List not showing in O365 Admin

Tags: sharepoint, exchange-server

I created a Dynamic Distribution List in my exchange online(this should hold all my employee, I was planning to use it in my Power Automate) but after 3 hours of creating it, its still not showing up in my M365 Admin Center. Anyone know if it will even show up here and if yes how long does it takes?

Below: Exchange Admin Center and the DDL I created
[image]
Below: Screenshot of my M365 Admin Center
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't show up in M365 admin center. It's also not possible to use the DDL's group id in power automate to get a list of the members.

The best explanation I could find was from https://office365itpros.com/2020/11/23/exchange-online-dynamic-distribution-lists/

Short explanation:

- "A DDL is composed of...An Exchange Online object which is not synchronized to Azure AD. A DDL only exists in EXODS."
- "...because DDLs are not Azure AD objects, you can’t create or manage them through the Azure AD portal or the Microsoft 365 admin center."